# GPU TensorFlow for Jetpack 4.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, nvidia, nvidia-jetson

I would like to ask one thing about the newest Nvidia release of Jetpack OS 4.4.
When I click [here](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/) for looking a release versions in `v42` and `v43` it has two folders `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` for cpu and gpu version. But when I click `v44` it has only one folder, just `tensorflow` and versions inside. Does it means that for the Jetpack 4.4 is not a Tensorflow with GPU support released?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a name change nothing more the so-called `tensorflow-gpu` is now called `tensorflow`

> Note: As of the 20.02 TensorFlow release, the package name has changed from tensorflow-gpu to tensorflow. See the section on Upgrading TensorFlow for more information.

**Check more [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html#install)**